# Error while insert items to context EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got have an error when insert items in my Seed Method

```
public class ContexInitializerDropAlways : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DomainDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DomainDbContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            List<Tour> tours = new List<Tour>
            {
                new Tour
                {
                    Price = 800.00m,
                    StartedOn = DateTime.Now,
                    EndedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                    Nights = 15
                },
                new Tour
                {
                    Price = 650.00m,
                    StartedOn = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
                    EndedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2),
                    Nights = 10
                },
                new Tour
                {
                    Price = 350m,
                    StartedOn = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
                    EndedOn = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
                    Nights = 5
                }
            };

            List<Country> countries = new List<Country>
            {
                new Country
                {
                    Name = "Австрия"
                },
                new Country
                {
                    Name = "Греция"
                },
                new Country
                {
                    Name = "Турция"
                }
            };

            countries[0].Tours.Add(tours[0]);
            countries[1].Tours.Add(tours[1]);
            countries[2].Tours.Add(tours[2]);

            context.Countries.AddRange(countries);
            context.SaveChanges();            
        }
    }
```

> Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Countries'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Countries'. The duplicate key
>   value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000). The statement has
>   been terminated.

Comment: Do you have a primary key in the table?

Comment: Yes, I do.
http://goo.gl/njrpWu
http://goo.gl/yWeWFX

Comment: Have you tried this?

new Country
{
   Name = "...";
   Id = Guid.NewGuid();
}

Answer (score 1):

In your `Country` class, please add the key attribute.

```
public class Country
{ 
    [Key] 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Then in your code:

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country>
        {
            new Country
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                Name = "Австрия"
            },
             // etc.
        };
```

The [example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is the solution:

```
public class CountryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
{
    public CountryConfiguration()
    {
        Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```